# Eclipse can't find files

Tags: java, file, io

I was trying to program a simple program on java when suddnely I couldn't open any file. I wrote a program to see if eclipse can even find the file - and it didn't work either. But when I try it in CMD it works perfectly. Why? Thanks.
Example: http://prntscr.com/7qn9gm

Comment: Try to print `file.getCanonicalPath()`, this will probably show a different folder then you expect

Comment: Try checking by printing `file.getAbsolutePath();`. By this you can check where java is searching the file.

Comment: Did you already tried using this relative path  `./textures/icon.png`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base path of an eclipse project is its root folder. Try changing the file path to "src/textures/icon.png".

Answer (score 0):

To access a file in a specific package, you could do

from a static method

```
File file = new File(Yourclass.class.getResource("/your/package/name/filename"));
```

So in your case

`File file = new File(Main.class.getResource("/textures/icon.png"))`;

From a non-static method, you could do

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/textures.icon.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize  file instance like this

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/textures/icon.png");
```

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns path of your project folder.